# how to create an object using self?

Tags: objective-c

I thought I understood the use of self while referring to anything in the current class. After encountering this warning and subsequent run failure, I have googled many variants of "define self" or "usage of self" and gotten nowhere. This problem is how to create an object without the warning, and understand why.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject {  
   Foo *obj;  
}  
-(void)beta;  
@end  

#import "Foo.h"  
@implementation Foo  
   -(void)beta{  
   obj = [self new];      // 'Foo' may not respond to '-new'  
}  
@end
```

Note, if I substitute `Foo` for `self`, there's no problem. I thought the class name and self were equivalent, but obviously the compiler doesn't think so.

1. Perhaps an explanation of what's wrong here will not only solve my problem but also enlighten my understanding of the usage of `self`.
2. Are there any tutorials about proper usage of self? I couldn't find anything beyond something like "`self` is the receiver of the message," which didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self` references the receiver of a message, so in this specific case, `self` references the object on which `-beta` was invoked. (Within the scope of a class method, `self` references the class' `Class` object)

Now, since `self` in this case references the object that the method was invoked on, the compiler gives you a warning because `new` is not an instance method of `Foo`. `new` is a *class method* inherited from `NSObject`. So, the correct way to do this would be to retrieve the `Class` object from `self`, then invoke `new` on that:

```
- (void) beta {  
  obj = [[self class] new];
}
```

Comment: This works nicely. +new takes [self class].  Then I can use self or obj to call a -method.  [won't take a CR here. sorry]-(void)beta{
//Foo *obj; in .h
 // obj = [self new];  fails here - warning, run failure
 obj = [[self class] new];
 [obj alpha];
// [self alpha] also works here;
}

-(void)alpha{
 NSLog(@"alpha");
 return;
}

Comment: @Nick, if I sufficiently answered your question, then please accept it by clicking on the hollow checkmark to the left of my answer.

Comment: This answers my question, but I now realize that I didn't completely understand it. In the first sentence, exactly what is "the object on which -beta was invoked"?

Comment: @Nick Say you had an instance of `Foo` created like this: `Foo *foo = [Foo new]; [foo beta];`, in this case, the variable `foo` is the object on which `beta` is invoked.

Comment: Let's see if I understand. In AppDelegate, I created fobj=[Foo new];then I called -beta with [fobj beta]; So fobj is self in -beta?  Then I can use obj further on in Foo.

Comment: Hooray! Thank you. You have no idea how much time I've spent with Google trying to track this down with no results. Just by  playing with it, I had sometimes gotten something that worked, but I need to understand why and never was able to figure it out. This does it for me.

Comment: I hate to belabor this, but if fobj and self are the same, I would expect them to have the same address. When I NSLog-ed them, different addresses came out. This window closes when I put in a CR, so please excuse the run-together log from the Debugger Console. I have no idea what the first line _CFS... means.2010-12-24 17:05:37.175 objnew[799:a0f] __CFServiceControllerBeginPBSLoadForLocalizations timed out while talking to pbs
2010-12-24 17:05:37.193 objnew[799:a0f] fobj = <Foo: 0x1001388b0>
2010-12-24 17:05:37.194 objnew[799:a0f] self = 1280176

Comment: Please disregard my last comment. Sorry. Something must have been wrong. I now get the same description from both self and fobj.  2010-12-25 18:10:42.345 objnew[608:a0f] fobj = <Foo: 0x100527080>
2010-12-25 18:10:42.347 objnew[608:a0f] self = <Foo: 0x100527080> Yes! They must be the same.